# PostGIS Topology result still has gaps and overlap

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, topology

I have been trying to build a Topology in Postgis with 4000+ polygons. They are not cleaned, with a lot of gaps and overlaps. After using ST_MakeValid, creating the topology and adding topogeom column, I have realized running the toTopoGeom in one go doesn't work as it often gets stopped by different kinds of exception. Then, I tried to add the polygons to the topology row by row, with the SQL statement below:

```
create or replace procedure topo(numberofrows int)
language plpgsql
as $$
declare 
    v_counter     INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
   loop
       begin
        v_counter := v_counter + 1;
        EXIT WHEN v_counter > numberofrows;
        UPDATE p_table SET topogeom = topology.toTopoGeom(geom,'p_topo',1,0.000012) where gid = v_counter;      
        raise notice 'gid % done', v_counter;
      exception
        when others then
          raise notice 'gid % didnt work, %', v_counter,sqlerrm;
          rollback;
      end;
      commit;
   END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

With this method, exceptions are skipped and then I can handle them with bigger/smaller tolerance. However, when I check the result with Qgis topology checker on the layer p_table.topogeom, there are still 500+ gaps and overlaps (from 4000+). topology.ValidateTopology returns zero error. I have checked these slivers manually, they are smaller than the tolerance and are expected to be cleaned. This problem is sometimes fixed when I extract those polygons, create a new file and new topology and run toTopoGeom together.

POSTGIS="3.2.1 5fae8e5" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="140" GEOS="3.8.0-CAPI-1.13.1 " PROJ="6.3.1" LIBXML="2.9.10" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"

[gap1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL4vt.png)
[gap2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8BAJ.png)

I have tested with EPSG:4326 WGS84 with 0.000012 tolerance and EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator with 1m tolerance, Multipolygon and Polygon as input, or to use ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology first. Unfortunately these slivers still exist. Does anyone have experience with this issue? Its my first ever question on stackoverflow so please let me know what else should I provide.

Comment: `ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology` doesn't preserve the topology **between** polygons, it just makes sure that you get the same geometry out as went in.

Comment: @IanTurton Thank you for the clarification. Would you have an idea about this issue? I understand that PostGIS topology may not be the best tool for geo data cleaning, yet I would like to understand the mechanism.